# Large Auto Increment IDs

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, auto-increment

I'm having a strange issue with some auto-inc IDs on a table, where instead of going up by 1 each time, it seems to be going up by 10 each time.

I'm using the

- ClearDB MySQL Addon for Heroku
- PHP 5.5.15
- Apache 2.4.10
- Laravel dev branch (4.something)

I've created the database via artisan's migrate functionality, My migration for the database table is

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCheckinTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('checkins', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('visitor_id');
            $table->integer('meeting_id');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('checkins');
    }

}
```

However when Im creating a new entry via this

```
    $this->checkin = new Checkin;
    $this->checkin->visitor_id = $this->id;
    $this->checkin->meeting_id = $this->nextMeetingId();
    $this->checkin->save();
```

The Checkin Class looks like

```
<?php

class Checkin extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'checkins';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('updated_at', 'visitor_id');

    protected $fillable = array();

    public function meeting(){
        return $this->hasOne('Meeting','id', 'meeting_id');
    }

    public function client(){
        return $this->hasOne('Visitor','id','visitor_id');
    }

}
```

However after F5ing and adding multiple entries the database table now looks like

```
id  visitor_id meeting_id updated_at created_at

1   1   0   2014-08-04 21:25:25 2014-08-04 21:25:25
11  1   0   2014-08-04 21:35:54 2014-08-04 21:35:54
21  1   0   2014-08-04 21:35:57 2014-08-04 21:35:57
31  1   0   2014-08-04 21:35:59 2014-08-04 21:35:59
41  1   0   2014-08-04 21:36:01 2014-08-04 21:36:01
51  1   0   2014-08-04 21:36:03 2014-08-04 21:36:03
```

As you can see the id's is going up by 10 each time rather than 1.

So if anybody knows the reason for this, please update me :)

Many thanks

Comment: Try setting `SET @@auto_increment_increment=1` and  `SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment=1;`

Comment: http://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq#general_16

Comment: @Razor Ah brill, I guess that explains why that happens, I was completely assuming that it was my code causing the issue! So I guess it should be fine to leave it as it is then?

Comment: It's a common technique used by DBAs to increase auto_increment offset. Short answer - yes, it's fine if you leave it as is. auto_increment's job is just to uniquely identify a row so there's nothing wrong in leaving it be.

Comment: Thanks all for your input, I've added an answer below for anybody else experiencing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an answer for others experiencing this issue.

The reason for the big steps was due to a MySQL Configuration that ClearDB had implimented.

Their reasoning for doing this is listed here: http://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq#general_16 (Thanks Razor for this)

If you need to investigate your increment settings yourself you can run the following query

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
```

this will output something like

```
auto_increment_increment    10
auto_increment_offset   1
```

So you can see the reason for my jumps was because this was set to 10.

As @Juergen d said you should be able to change this if you *need* to by the following queries.

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment=1;
```

I however didnt change this setting as ClearDB set it for a reason, and I was only querying this incase it was something i had mis-configured.

Case Closed, Thanks to everybody for their input.