# Alter MySQL auto_increment with Heroku ClearDB addon

Tags: mysql, heroku, cleardb

My Rails app is hosted on Heroku. I have a problem with MySQL incrementing by 10:  [Large Auto Increment IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127226/large-auto-increment-ids)

I really want to change it to 1, and I have found the SQL command for that. However, I cannot figure out how to connect to mysql via Heroku to perform it. Is there a workaround? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to the database hosted by ClearDB using your local `mysql` command line client application. First you'll need to check your database URL to get the necessary connection details, so run `heroku config` and you should see a line that looks something like this:

```
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: mysql://abcdef01234567:9876543@us-cdbr-iron-east-01.cleardb.net/heroku_fedcba76543210?reconnect=true
```

The URL contains the username, password, host and database name in the format:

```
mysql://username:password@host/database?reconnect=true
```

With those four pieces of information you can connect to your database. Using the (made up) example database URL as an example:

```
mysql --user=abcdef01234567 --password9876543 --host=us-cdbr-iron-east-01.cleardb.net heroku_fedcba76543210
```